# Vuetify TreeView displayed incorrectly

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm a beginner in Vue, so please bear with my question.
I try to create a simple selectable tree, but for some reason it is displayed incorrectly. Instead of buttons, words remain.
I can't think of anything else I could have forgotten to do.

[image: Edit Vue Template]

I tried adding a link to the vuetify CSS file (import 'verify/disk/verify.min. css';), but after that the image becomes even less readable. The link to material design icons is in the file index.html

How can I fix this, please?

Without CSS:

[image: without css]

With CSS:

[image: with css]

Comment: You have not included the Vuetify CSS file **and/or** the MDI icons stylesheet.

Comment: I tried inserting CSS in a file main.js (import 'verify/disk/verify.min. css';), but this makes the image even less readable. But the link to MDI icons seems to be in the file index.html. Or is that not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Vuetify 2.x and it (contrary to 1.x) requires that in your Vue constructor

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>",
  vuetify: new Vuetify() // <--- the important thing !!!
});
```

Also - you should wrap your content (in `App.vue`) inside `<v-app>` - otherwise the arrow icons on tree nodes will not switch between expanded/collapsed.

Comment: Thank you, these tips helped me a lot, now everything works as it should! I don't have enough reputation to evaluate the answer, but I definitely mark it as a solution!